# Is the JQuery cookie plugin able to use custom aliases?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am trying to use the JQuery cookie plugin in my project but I'm running into some trouble. Because I need to use the prototype library along with the JQuery library I used the `JQuery.noConflict()` method to assign $j as the JQuery alias. Unfortunately, even once I have loaded jquery.cookie.js into my page, `$j.cookie('name','value')` returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (selector, context){
  //The JQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new JQuery.fn.init(selector,context);
} has no method 'cookie'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it is out of the box. Though, I'm sure it's possible for you to change it up a bit. Replace the instances of jQuery with '$' for instance in a block as such

```
(function($) {
  $.cookie = ...
})(jQuery);
```

I don't see why that wouldn't work, but I have no idea. I'm just speculating ;)

Comment: Just solved my own problem, apparently I downloaded it wrong... Thanks for the answer.